# Spring MVC Hibernate Pagination with JSP

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to achieve the pagination in Spring MVC with Hibernate. I tried to follow a few tutorials, no luck. Details explanation would be great.

DAO Implementation:

```
    public List<Blog> getBlogList() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("From Blog ORDER BY postCreated DESC");
    query.setFirstResult(0);
    query.setMaxResults(5);
    List<Blog> blogList = query.list();
    // total count
    String countQ = "SELECT count (b.id) from Blog b";
    Query countQuery = session.createQuery(countQ);
    Long countResults = (Long)countQuery.uniqueResult();
    // last page
    int pageSize = 5;
    int lastPageNumber = (int) ((countResults / pageSize) + 1);

    return blogList;
}
```

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView listAllBlogPosts(ModelMap model) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ADD_NEW_BLOG_POST);
    model.addAttribute("blog", new Blog());
    model.addAttribute("blogList", blogService.getBlogList());
    return mav;
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/taglibs.jsp" %>
        <div class="blog">
            <c:forEach items="${blogList}" var="blog">
                <h1>${blog.title}</h1>

                <p class="lead"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;by&nbsp;${blog.author}</p>

                <p class="fa fa-calendar">&nbsp;Posted on&nbsp;<span
                        class="badge badge-success">${blog.postCreated}</span></p>

                <p><span>${blog.content}</span></p>

                <p class="fa fa-tags"><a href=""><span class="badge badge-info">Random</span></a></p>
                <hr>
            </c:forEach>
```

I wanted to calculate the total numbers of pages, 5 recent post, and the pagination button in the bottom of the page to navigate to another page.

Comment: Did you consider use of Spring Data JPA?

Comment: I tried, unfortunately I couldn't achieve.